# Is there a way to automatically change git username based on cloned repository url?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

If I am cloning a repository from, say, bitbucket, I would like to use a different git username on my commits (`git config user.name`).

Is there a way to do this automatically. For example, if I run this in terminal

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:...
```

Have it automatically set `git config user.name` to something I always want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is to make a "myclone" alias or however you want to do it, that adds the extra setup check.  Most projects that need to deal with this have a `.mailmap` file (which Git supports natively) to set up alternate/superseded identity mappings to the project-specific preferred identity. With the mailmap if your project switches hosting you don't have to further customize and mistakes are trivial to deal with, it's just a question of what works best for you.